# Shutting down linux gracefully from the file system?

Tags: linux, power-management, raspbian

I've just managed to get raspberry pi network boot working (It's great to be free of the sd card). I've worked with network boot before but only for imaging, never with a fully functional remote file system. Since I'm now dealing with 2 separate systems that represent the pi's state (the pi with its ram, cpu registers and the like and a server that contains the file system). I was thinking either going down would be pretty bad as it would leave the file system in a potential unsafe state (as if power had just been pulled).

So, I started wondering, is there any convenient way to shutdown the storage server but first trigger the pi to shut down? I know I could ssh and run a shutdown script but I was thinking as I already had access to the root filesystem is there an change that could be made that would result in immediate graceful shutdown? I've considered a adding a job to cron but that wouldn't be immediate or doing something unpleasant to a system file but that would hardly be graceful. This question is mostly hypothetical as there are already plenty of possible shutdown options but I was curious about a pure file system approach using only the base rasbian install.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't do this - what follows is a purely academic exercise.

Now:
We have to understand the differences between filesystem metadata and file data. Changing the first while the file system is mounted would result in corruption, but changing the file data is another thing. So this would work (while still being not a good idea)

- Write a flag file to the file system **on the Pi**. This should be long enough to make sure, its content is stored in a separate block, not in the inode.
- Create a cron job on the Pi, that
- - drops caches (so as to really read the file)
- - reads the file
- - uses the file content to decide on a shutdown
- Find this block **on the storage server**
- To shut down the Pi, change this block to a content, that makes the Pi initiate shutdown on next cron job (make sure, the content is what you expect before!).

Comment: While I am certain that this would work it don't meet either of the two goals of being immediate (have to wait for the cron job to run) or work without modifying the base install (would require writing a cron job)